# How to avoid the Eclipse text editor to trim all lines, ie. to remove all trailing whitespace?

Tags: eclipse, text, whitespace, text-editor, removing-whitespace

On saving a plain-text file in the Eclipse standard text editor (NB: This is not about Java files!), Eclipse removes trailing whitespace of all lines.

Is there a way to suppress this behavior? I could not find any option for this.

Comment: AnyEdit Tools have that feature. See if it is enabled if you have it installed: `AnyEdit Tools->Auto - Convert->Remove trailing whitespace`

Comment: I do not have AnyEdit installed, but, okay, that would be a solution. I am still puzzled that there seems no way to configure the standard Eclipse text editor to behave like one, ie. not to perform additional unwanted actions that change the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions and configure it  not to remove trailing whitespace.

Comment: No, that has an effect only on files opened in the Java editor, and not on plain-text files.